# Using Google Optimize without visual editor?

Tags: javascript, ab-testing, google-optimize

We are trying to create A/B testing framework for our site.
We have decided to use google optimize tool. but we don't need the their built in visual editor, only use the their experiment management (variants percentage, Objective, Targeting, Reporting) and to make all the changes in our javascript code (written with AngularJS framework).

So from my research so far i've seen this:

```
function gtag() {dataLayer.push(arguments)}

function implementExperimentA(value) {
  if (value ==  '0') {
    // Provide code for visitors in the original.
  } else if (value == '1') {
    // Provide code for visitors in first variant.
  } else if (value == '2') {
    // Provide code for visitors in section variant.
  }
  ...
}

gtag('event', 'optimize.callback', {
    name: '<experiment_id_A>',
    callback: implementExperimentA
 });
```

and I use this way for getting the variant

```
google_optimize &&  google_optimize.get('<experiment_id_A>');

for example 
var variantId = google_optimize.get('someTest');

if (variantId == '0'){
   // blue button
}
else if (variantId == '1'){
   // red button
}
```

what is the proper way to do what i'm looking for.
and should i use google optimize for this purpose? (AB testing only in code without editor)

Answer (score 0):

The [support article](https://support.google.com/optimize/answer/9059383?hl=en), from which you have also taken the first code snippet, provides a complete example, although leaves up to you to fill the possible changes within the different variants, represented by `value`.

Actually, there's no need to read the variant, as you try to achieve it in your second code, as it is provided in the callback function, and even experiment name can be read.

Please see this full example, and feel free to try, and enhance it. All you need to do, is to set up an A/B-test, of which you can match the targeting rules (so the preview mode will work properly), and you can skip the editor for this experiment. You'll need to supply the experiment ID from your own experiment.

```
<!-- Just some static welcome text -->
<p id="main">This is a test page for Google Optimize JS API</p> 

<!-- Some text, that will change based on the experiment variant -->
<p id="placeholder">Eagerly waiting for an AB-test to start</p>

<!-- Main script  -->
<script>
    //mandatory call based on the support article
    function gtag() {dataLayer.push(arguments)};

    //callback function, containing actual changes
    function implementExperimentA(value, name) {
        var newText = 'Something has gone wrong. No variant found for';    

        //go through variants, and apply change for specific variants, identified by their index
        //note, the same index is present in Google Analyitcs, in the Variant dimension 
        if (value ==  '0') {    
            newText = "Bummer, you've ended up in the control group in";  
        } else if (value == '1') {  
            newText = "You've made it! You are in test group of";  
        }     

        //apply selected text to placeholder paragraph
        var el = document.getElementById('placeholder');  
        el.innerText = newText + ' experiment ' + name;  
    }   

    //mandatory call based on the support article
    //assign your experiment's ID to callback function
    gtag('event', 'optimize.callback', {    
        name: 'EXPERIMENT_ID_FROM_OPTIMIZE',    
        callback: implementExperimentA 
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main reason to use Google Optimize is because of the visual editor.  If you want to write code instead, it's much better to run the experiment yourself without adding a huge blocking script tag to your site.

Assigning users to a variation is pretty easy - Google isn't doing anything magic there.  Here's a simple proof-of-concept:

```
// Simple hash function
function hashFnv32a(str: string): number {
  let hval = 0x811c9dc5;
  const l = str.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    hval ^= str.charCodeAt(i);
    hval +=
      (hval << 1) + (hval << 4) + (hval << 7) + (hval << 8) + (hval << 24);
  }
  return hval >>> 0;
}

// Persistent user id stored in localStorage
let id = localStorage.get("anonId")
if(!id) {
  id = Math.random()
  localStorage.set("anonId", id)
}

// Hash the user id with the experiment name
const n = hashFnv32a(id + "someTest")%1000/1000;

// Show the chosen variation to the user
if(n < 0.34) {
  // Original
}
else if(n < 0.67) {
  // First variant
}
else {
  // Second variant
}
```

I made an open source library for this that's a little more production-ready with some nice targeting features added if you want to check it out - https://github.com/growthbook/growthbook-js